# MySQL SELECT WHERE EQUALS syntax

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a MySQL database table called Participant that looks something like this:

```
(idParticipant) - (firstName) - (secondName) - (gender) - (dob)

118   John     Dunne         m    1944-04-01

117   Mary     Delaney       f    1955-05-03

116   Adam     Bermingham    m    1920-01-01

115   Eamonn   Reilly        m    1987-03-19

114   Aaron    Duane         m    1990-07-08

119   Sarah    Calvin        f    1977-07-17
```

When I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `Participant` WHERE idParticipant = 118 OR 119;
```

I think I should get the following result:

```
118  John    Dunne       m    1944-04-01

119  Sarah   Calvin      f    1977-07-17
```

But instead it just returns the whole table. Where am I going wrong in my MySQL syntax?

Comment: Why would you downvote the question? It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `WHERE idParticipant IN (118, 119);`

My guess is that MySQL is implicitly converting the value of 119 to a Boolean true value, so you are saying: `WHERE idParticipant = 118 OR TRUE;`, thus including all the rows. The equality is evaluated first, followed by the Boolean `OR`.

Comment: Ah yes, of course... My brain is fried at the moment. Should have seen that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the statement after the `WHERE` as a boolean statement on its own.  I mean,  your expression should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Participant` WHERE idParticipant = 118 OR idParticipant = 119;
```